# How to ignore comment changes and blank line changes in two files?

Tags: java, svn, unix, diff

I am using "svn diff" command to get changes at directory level but this diff include all the comment line changes and blank line changes. How can I ignore these values?

ex:

**diff file:**

```
+ import......

+ some code
+ #comment
+ blank line
+ some code
```

this should be as below:(comments and blank lines should be ommitted)

```
+ import......

+ some code
+ some code
```

It would be good also if i can process the first file using Java or unix and delete these blank and comment lines?

Answer (score 1):

`svn diff -r 100:200 -x -b > file.diff`

for whitespaces Use `-x --ignore-space-change` or `-x --ignore-all-space`. (See `svn -h diff`.)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the `#` is your comment character, then you can use `egrep` command to filter out the lines you don't want

```
svn diff <args> | egrep -v '^\+(#|$)'
```

What is egrep ?

The ***egrep*** command is shortcut for grep binary, but with one exception, when grep is invoked as `egrep` the grep binary activates its internal logic as it would be called as `grep -E`.
What the difference you will ask.. and the difference is that -E parameter enables usage of extended regexp patterns, it will allow you using of such ***meta-symbols*** as +, ? or | (pipe). They aren't ordinal characters like we used to have in words or filenames but control commands for grep binary itself.